# How can I expand a canvas to the entire viewport in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas

I've got a static, test version of my website hosted here:

http://alexgolec.staticloud.com/

but when I fire it up in Firefox, the canvas does not resize properly. I think the offending line of code is here:

```
    var _docHeight = (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : 
                      document.body.offsetHeight;
    var _docWidth = (document.width !== undefined) ? document.width : 
                     document.body.offsetWidth;

    ctx.canvas.width = _docWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = _docHeight;
```

This code works correctly in WebKit browsers, but Gecko seems to barf on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page looks great. But I don't think you get it right on Chrome either, as the background is not re-painted after resize.

You should attach an event listener to onResize event, and call `canvasMain()` from that handler to repaint every thing with new canvas size.

About the sizing problem, you should use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. Because `<body>` is packed to the content which is only 320px height, so it won't fill up the whole page.